# Find yaml and yml files using glob.glob()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling with finding yaml and yml files. What I want is to print two lists of files and check if there is any extra file. I can't figure out what is the regex of glob.glob

I did:

```
glob.glob('/data/config/**y*ml', recursive=True)))
```

But it's finding also xml files.

What I have right now is:

```
ymlFilenamesListA = sorted(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob('/data/config/**{yml,yaml}', recursive=True)))
ymlFilenamesListB = sorted(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob('/app/config/**{yml,yaml}', recursive=True)))
print(ymlFilenamesListA)
print(ymlFilenamesListB)

def compareList(l1,l2):
   l1.sort()
   l2.sort()
   if(l1==l2):
      return "No new files"
   else:
      print("Found new files: ")
      print(list(set(l1) - set(l2)))
      return sys.exit(1)

print(compareList(ymlFilenamesListA,ymlFilenamesListB))
```

And my output is:

```
./find.py
[]
[]
No new files
```

How can I compare two trees of files and check if there is any missing or some extra?

Comment: Do all the yml and yaml files exist in /data/config? If yes, then all you need is '/data/config/\*.y\*ml' no need for recursion. If you need to scan sub-directories then '/data/config/**/\*.y\*ml' with recursive=True

Comment: @LancelotduLac Okay, I did it before, it works, but there is another problem.
`print(list(set(l1) - set(l2)))`
this one right here stops working, it should print the difference between those two lists, but I get `[]`. But if in my blob.blob regex I put *.yaml then everything is fine and I get the difference between the lists. `['circuitBreakerConfig2.yaml']` I just don't get it, why the extra * breaks the function.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I was substracting the shorter list from the longer list. If I do the opposite than I get the output.